# How to connect biometric device with sdk?

Tags: c#, asp.net, biometrics

SDK User manual:
https://www.scribd.com/doc/270839166/SBXPC-OCX-Reference-Manual-v3-03

Webform1.cs:

```
public string ip = "192.168.1.109";
 protected void Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                bool status = sbxpc.SBXPCDLL.ConnectTcpip(1, ip, 5005, 0);
                if (status)
                {

                    bool ss = sbxpc.SBXPCDLL.GetSerialNumber(1, out ip);
                    Button1.Text = "connected";
                    Response.Write("success" + ip);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Response.Write(ee);
            }
        }
```

sbxpc.SBXPCDLL.cs:

```
[DllImport("SBXPCDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
static extern byte _ConnectTcpip(Int32 dwMachineNumber, ref IntPtr lpszIPAddress, Int32 dwPortNumber, Int32 dwPassWord);
public static bool ConnectTcpip(Int32 dwMachineNumber, string lpszIPAddress, Int32 dwPortNumber, Int32 dwPassWord)
{
    if (lpszIPAddress == null)
        return false;
    IntPtr string_in = Marshal.StringToBSTR(lpszIPAddress);
    try
    {
        byte ret = _ConnectTcpip(dwMachineNumber, ref string_in, dwPortNumber, dwPassWord);
        return ret > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeBSTR(string_in);
    }
}
```

The above code works at some time only,first time connected with device after some time it doesn't connect.I don't know why it happens. Could any one help me to rectify.

Comment: For every Connect... there should be a matching Disconnect/DisconnectAll call.